# Create a conditional pattern for validating phone number in Screen Flow

Tags: visual-workflow, regular-expressions, screen-flow

I am using a screen flow to capture information that will create multiple records, and one of the fields I need to capture is a Phone field.  Depending on a value set previously (Country), the phone number needs to have different number of digits.
I was hoping I could create a resource that will be the Pattern used to validate the phone number, but have not been able to figure out how to do this.

I've tried to create a formula resource with text output using the following structure

```
CASE({CountryField},
CO,"^\d{10}$",
US,"^\d{10}$"
"^\d{12}$")
```

But I keep getting a syntax error.

Does anyone know if it **is at all possible** to have a pattern that is conditional in this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three errors in your formula expression

1. Missing comma at end of this line: `US,"^\d{10}$"`
2. Missing surrounding quotes around `CO` and `US`
3. The backslashes have to be double-escaped

Corrected

```
CASE({!$CountryField},
"CO","^\\d{10}$",
"US","^\\d{10}$",
"^\\d{12}$")
```

Comment: thanks!!  I'm super-happy that a) this is possible to do and b) you fixed my formula errors :)